# How can I set Mail.app *back* to the mailto: protocol handler?

Tags: mail.app, google-chrome

After following the steps in:

- [How can I use Gmail as the default mail client app in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/3029/151730)

How can I *undo* these settings?

**How can I set Mail.app *back* to being the default `mailto:` protocol handler?**

I tried unsetting the `mailto:` protocol in chrome://settings/handlers, but the only result is that now `mailto:` links don't open *at all*.  (They still switch focus to Chrome.)

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/548122/504387), the file that needs to be edited is `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`.  However, checking the file contents with the `file` command shows that it is a binary file:

```
$ file /Users/(me)/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist
/Users/(me)/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist: Apple binary property list
```

What else can I try?

(I am running Mac OS 10.7.4.)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest mucking with LaunchServices unless you know exactly what you're doing. Also, `mailto` is a protocol already handled by the system. The question you linked was about defining new protocols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the General pane of Mail settings, there should be an option for setting the default mail client.

Comment: While you definitely answer the question, providing more information (such as what the setting is called or a screenshot) would flesh out your post.

Comment: D'oh!  I didn't think to check *there*.  Of course, Apple.  Why wouldn't a system-wide default be set from a single application's preferences pane?  Makes perfect sense.  (@tubedogg, that really is all the info needed to find the setting.)